# Problem with Q-learning/TD(0) for Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, tic-tac-toe, q-learning, temporal-difference

I have some bug in my code that apparently prevents my actors from learning the game properly. The code is an implementation of tabular q-learning, where the intention is to simultaneously train two actors playing against each other. The expected result is two q-tables, one for each player, that enables each actor to perform optimally (i.e. all games end in draw). I am using the epsilon-greedy policy, where epsilon is the exploration probability, which decreases exponentially after 10k epochs. Furthermore, I use this equation to update the Q factors: [image]

I have tried a lot of parameters, so I do not think it is down to anything like that. I suspect there may be either something related to the training algorithm or something related to how I perform the updates of the Q-values. If anyone have the time to take a look and point out any obvious blunders, I would be very grateful. :) Code is included below.

```
import numpy as np

ROWS = 3
COLS = 3


class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self, player1, player2):
        self.player_symbol = 1
        self.player1 = player1
        self.player2 = player2
        self.current_player = player1
        self.other_player = player2
        self.board = np.zeros([ROWS, COLS])
        self.game_over = False
        self.winner = None

    def get_available_positions(self):
        available_positions = []
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(COLS):
                if self.board[row, col] == 0:
                    available_positions.append((row, col))
        return available_positions

    def get_hash(self):
        board_hash = str(self.board.reshape(ROWS * COLS))
        return board_hash

    def update_board(self, position):
        self.board[position] = self.player_symbol

    def check_winner(self):
        for row in range(ROWS):
            rowsum = np.sum(self.board[row, :])
            if rowsum == 3:
                self.game_over = True
                return 1
            if rowsum == -3:
                self.game_over = True
                return -1
        for col in range(COLS):
            colsum = np.sum(self.board[:, col])
            if colsum == 3:
                self.game_over = True
                return 1
            if colsum == -3:
                self.game_over = True
                return -1
        diag_sum1 = 0
        diag_sum2 = 0
        for index in range(ROWS):
            diag_sum1 += self.board[index, index]
            diag_sum2 += self.board[index, COLS - 1 - index]
        if diag_sum1 == 3 or diag_sum2 == 3:
            self.game_over = True
            return 1
        if diag_sum1 == -3 or diag_sum2 == -3:
            self.game_over = True
            return -1
        if len(self.get_available_positions()) == 0:
            self.game_over = True
            return 0
        self.game_over = False
        return None

    def give_reward(self):
        if self.winner == 1:
            if self.player_symbol == 1:
                self.current_player.assign_reward(1)
                self.other_player.assign_reward(-1)
            else:
                self.current_player.assign_reward(-1)
                self.other_player.assign_reward(1)
        elif self.winner == -1:
            if self.player_symbol == -1:
                self.current_player.assign_reward(1)
                self.other_player.assign_reward(-1)
            else:
                self.current_player.assign_reward(-1)
                self.other_player.assign_reward(1)
        elif self.winner == 0:
            if self.player_symbol == 1:
                self.current_player.assign_reward(0)
                self.other_player.assign_reward(0)
            else:
                self.current_player.assign_reward(0)
                self.other_player.assign_reward(0)

    def reset_board(self):
        self.board = np.zeros([ROWS, COLS])
        self.game_over = False
        self.player_symbol = 1
        self.winner = None
        self.current_player = 1
        self.player1.reward = 0
        self.player2.reward = 0

    def switch_players(self):
        self.player_symbol *= -1
        if self.current_player == self.player1:
            self.current_player = self.player2
            self.other_player = self.player1
        else:
            self.current_player = self.player1
            self.other_player = self.player2

    def keep_score(self, epoch):
        if self.winner == 1 or self.winner == -1:
            self.current_player.won_rounds.append(epoch)
            self.current_player.wins += 1
            self.other_player.losses += 1
        if self.winner == 0:
            self.current_player.draw_rounds.append(epoch)
            self.current_player.draws += 1
            self.other_player.draw_rounds.append(epoch)
            self.other_player.draws += 1

    def train(self, epochs=1000):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            self.current_player = self.player1
            self.other_player = self.player2
            self.player_symbol = 1
            if epoch % 1000 == 0:
                print(f'Epoch {epoch}.')
            if epoch > 10000:
                if epoch % 100 == 0:
                    self.current_player.epsilon = self.current_player.epsilon * 0.9
                    self.other_player.epsilon = self.other_player.epsilon * 0.9
            counter = 0
            while not self.game_over:
                self.current_player.add_state(self.board)
                self.current_player.add_qtable(self.board)
                available_positions = self.get_available_positions()
                player_action = self.current_player.choose_move(available_positions, self.board)
                self.update_board(player_action)
                self.winner = self.check_winner()
                if counter not in (0, 1):
                    self.current_player.update_qtable()
                self.current_player.last_move = player_action
                if self.winner is not None:
                    self.give_reward()
                    self.keep_score(epoch)
                    self.current_player.update_endgame_qtable()
                    self.other_player.update_endgame_qtable()
                self.switch_players()
                counter += 1
            self.current_player.reset_game_state()
            self.other_player.reset_game_state()
            self.reset_board()


class Player:
    def __init__(self, player_id, epsilon=0.9):
        self.game_states = []
        self.qtable = {}
        self.id = player_id
        self.alpha = 0.1
        self.gamma = 1.0
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.reward = 0
        self.draws = 0
        self.action = None
        self.last_move = None
        self.won_rounds = []
        self.lost_rounds = []
        self.draw_rounds = []

    @staticmethod
    def get_hash(board):
        board_hash = str(board.reshape(ROWS * COLS))
        return board_hash

    def choose_move(self, available_positions, current_board):
        rand = np.random.uniform()
        if rand <= self.epsilon:
            chosen_index = np.random.choice(len(available_positions))
            chosen_move = available_positions[chosen_index]
        else:
            largest_value = -np.inf
            new_board = np.copy(current_board)
            new_board_hash = self.get_hash(new_board)
            self.add_qtable(current_board)
            value_table = self.qtable.get(new_board_hash)
            position_list = []
            for position in available_positions:
                value = value_table[position]
                if value > largest_value:
                    largest_value = value
                    position_list = [position]
                elif value == largest_value:
                    position_list.append(position)
            chosen_index = np.random.choice(len(position_list))
            chosen_move = position_list[chosen_index]
        return chosen_move

    def assign_reward(self, reward):
        self.reward = reward

    @staticmethod
    def create_new_qtable(new_board):
        new_qtable = np.zeros([ROWS, COLS])
        for row in range(ROWS):
            for col in range(COLS):
                if np.abs(new_board[row, col]) == 1:
                    new_qtable[row, col] = np.nan
        return new_qtable

    def update_qtable(self):
        new_hash = self.get_hash(self.game_states[-1])
        if self.qtable.get(new_hash) is None:
            self.add_qtable(self.game_states[-1])
        new_state = self.get_hash(self.game_states[-1])
        old_state = self.get_hash(self.game_states[-2])
        future_best_q = np.nanmax(self.qtable[new_state])
        past_best_q = self.qtable[old_state][self.last_move]
        updated_qtable = np.copy(self.qtable[old_state])
        new_value = past_best_q + self.alpha * (self.gamma * future_best_q - past_best_q)
        updated_qtable[self.last_move] = new_value
        self.qtable[old_state] = updated_qtable

    def update_endgame_qtable(self):
        winner_key_hash = self.get_hash(self.game_states[-1])
        self.qtable[winner_key_hash][self.last_move] = self.reward

    def add_qtable(self, board):
        new_hash = self.get_hash(board)
        if self.qtable.get(new_hash) is None:
            self.qtable[new_hash] = self.create_new_qtable(board)

    def add_state(self, game_state):
        gs = np.copy(game_state)
        self.game_states.append(gs)

    def reset_game_state(self):
        self.reward = 0
        self.game_states = []


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_avg = 1
    n_epochs = 30000
    avg_results = np.zeros([n_avg, n_epochs])
    for i in range(n_avg):
        player1 = Player(1, epsilon=1.0)
        player2 = Player(-1, epsilon=1.0)
        game = TicTacToe(player1, player2)
        game.train(epochs=n_epochs)
        # print(player1.qtable)
        print(player2.qtable)
        avg_results[i, player1.won_rounds] = 1
        avg_results[i, player2.won_rounds] = -1
        print(f"Player 1 win ratio: {player1.wins / n_epochs}")
        print(f"Player 2 win ratio: {player2.wins / n_epochs}")
        print(f"Draw ratio: {player1.draws / n_epochs}")
```

EDIT: Oh, it DOES work! Apparently I had forgotten to update epsilon for one player! Also, my wife found some bugs (credit where credit is due...)